# Operator (Add Round Cube) doesn't work

Tags: objects

I can't change parameters e.g. size, location, rotation.

[image: Bottom left corner]

Answer (score 0):

If G. Garone's answer doesn't work and none of your operators work, then i have another possible solution. I've had this happen a few times to me already, using 2.8.

Just press F3 in the 3D view, then search for "Load Factory Settings". Click on it, and the problem should be fixed. Be sure to go through your settings again, enabling add-ons and changing whatever you need. Don't forget to save the settings afterwards!

Answer (score -1):

I think you enabled *"Manipulate Center Points"* option.

[image]

Just disable it and you should be able to move/rotate/scale your object.

More info about this option here: [Manipulate Center Points](http://hhps://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/manipulate_center_points.html)